# Error launching idea64.exe

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm

When I try to open idea64.exe (IntelliJ IDEA 64-bit version) I get the error "No JVM installation found. Please reinstall the product or install the JDK."

Why is this? I have both Java 8 Update 5 (64-bit) and Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 5 (64-bit) installed. Also, idea.exe (32-bit) works fine

Comment: If idea32 works ok, probably a '64 bit' issue. If you open up a command prompt, and type 'java -version -d64' it will confirm if the JVM on your path is a 64-bit one?

Comment: It's definitely 64-bit. I'll keep looking for the issue though

Comment: run idea.bat and check if there is any issue in starting up the jvm

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[According to JetBrains](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under), idea64.exe uses this JDK search sequence:

```
IDEA_JDK_64 environment variable
..\jre64 directory
system Registry
JDK_HOME environment variable
JAVA_HOME environment variable
```

If IDEA fails to auto-detect your JDK, try to set IDEA_JDK_64.

Comment: How would I do this? I cannot find IDEA_JDK_64

Comment: IDEA_JDK_64 is an environment variable: for a simple test open a cmd.exe, type "SET IDEA_JDK_64=..." where "..." is the full path to your JDK directory, look at the linked webpage, there is an example that reads "c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_17". Start `idea64.exe` from within this cmd shell by hand.

Comment: Thank you! I just had to use the SETX command in cmd.exe Works perfectly now! Thank you :)